In Kate editor, how to change the colors (text and/or background) of the contextual help popups?
I use Kate text editor, and there is a feature which I use a lot: the contextual popup help, on the editor's UI elements.
Recently the colors are changed (it may be due to an update, and/or to me switching to a new color scheme/theme), and the text became almost unreadable, because the color of the text of the popup and its background have become too similar, as shown in the following screenshots:


This question and relative answers clarify how to change the UI colors, but I fail to find the right specific setting for this specific pair of colors of the UI that I need to change.
Thanks in advance for any help!
